# Visual Studio Team Services Build cannot deploy test agent

Tags: build, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've got a VSTS build that is trying to deploy a test agent so I can run some Selenium tests and when I get to the "Deploy TestAgent on" build step, I am getting the following error:

> 2017-06-22T14:29:05.6157972Z ##[warning]Task 'DownloadTestAgent' for
>   machine vmtest43xxx.cloudapp.net:5986's Error : System.Exception: The
>   process cannot access the file 'C:\TestAgent\vstf_testagent.exe'
>   because it is being used by another process.

Also, if setting up a local build agent is a good workaround for this, I'm all ears, but so far I have had a lot of trouble trying to set up a local test agent. This seems weird since setting up a local build agent was relatively easy up to this point. Any suggestions on how I should set up a local agent? I've been trying to follow instructions from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment) and [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy to setup a local build agent, so try to setup a build agent:

Steps for windows:

1. Go to Admin page of Agent Pools (https://[account].visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool)
2. Click Download agent button
3. Unzip the downloaded file
4. Run Command Line as Administrator
5. Run config.cmd
6. Specify collection url (https://[account].visualstudio.com), Personal Access Token etc

More information, you can refer to: [Deploy an agent on Windows](http://It%E2%80%99s%20easy%20to%20setup%20a%20local%20build%20agent,%20so%20try%20to%20setup%20a%20build%20agent:).

You can specify Test Agent Location (can be access from build agent machine) for Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task to save time.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps my question was not clear. The main crux of my problem is with setting up a working test agent so I can run my selenium UI tests.  I'm not have trouble setting up the build agent. Yes, I agree that setting up a local build agent is easy and I am using that for now (although getting it to work as a windows service as my user instead of the network authority is tricky).

Comment: @DanCsharpster Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the detail build log on the OneDrive.